# How to specify in a query dates for the entire previous work week, regardless of the current day/date?

Tags: sql, db2

How can I make my query pull the data based off of the last full week 
(sunday to Saturday) regardless of the day the data is being pulled?

```
SELECT 
TLORDER.BILL_TO_CODE, 
TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER, 
DATE(LEG_DATE) LEG_DATE, 
DRIVER_ID, 
(SELECT DRIVER_TYPE FROM DRIVER WHERE DRIVER.DRIVER_ID = DRIVERPAY.DRIVER_ID), 
(SELECT TERMINAL_NUMBER FROM DRIVER WHERE DRIVER.DRIVER_ID = DRIVERPAY.DRIVER_ID) TERMINAL_NUMBER, 
(SELECT TERMINAL_ZONE FROM DRIVER WHERE DRIVER.DRIVER_ID = DRIVERPAY.DRIVER_ID) TERMINAL_ZONE, 
SUM(TOTAL_PAY_AMT) TOTAL_PAY, 
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(LS_LEG_DIST) FROM LEGSUM WHERE LS_TRIP_NUMBER = DRIVERPAY.TRIP_NUMBER),TLORDER.DISTANCE) MILES , 
TLORDER.DISTANCE, 
ORIGIN, 
TLORDER.START_ZONE_DESC, 
DESTINATION, 
TLORDER.END_ZONE_DESC 

     FROM DRIVERPAY 
        INNER JOIN TLORDER 
          ON TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID = DRIVERPAY.DETAIL_LINE_ID

WHERE 
     DATE(LEG_DATE) >= CURRENT DATE - 14 DAYS 
     AND PMT_STATE IN ('C','X','A') 

GROUP BY TLORDER.BILL_TO_CODE, TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER, DRIVER_ID, DISTANCE, ORIGIN, TLORDER.START_ZONE_DESC, DESTINATION, TLORDER.END_ZONE_DESC, DRIVERPAY.TRIP_NUMBER, LEG_DATE
ORDER BY TERMINAL_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the dates to retrieve with the function

> dayofweek_iso

It will return 1 for Mondays up to 7 for Sundays.

So it will be something like

```
current date - 7 days - dayofweek_iso(current date) days
```

This will substract one week from current date and additionally n days of the current week.